# Python concatenating different size arrays stored in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list 'Z' with:

```
import numpy as np
z[0] = np.random.normal( 0, 1, ( 500, 20 ) )
z[1] = np.random.normal( 0, 1, ( 500, 30 ) )
```

There are about 100 arrays in the list. I am using only size 2 list for illustration. The stored arrays are all of dimension 0 of 500

I want to achieve:

```
C = np.concatenate( ( z[0] , z[1] ),1)
```

I tried:

```
z1 = [ np.concatenate( z[ii], 1 ) for ii in range(0,len(z)) ]
```

but it still returns the original list and doesn't concatenate the stored arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concatenation for multidimensional arrays is somewhat ill-defined without specifying an axis along which to concatenate. I assume you want to stack your arrays horizontally because the number of rows is the same for both. The simplest call is

```
stacked = np.hstack(Z)
```

which will concatenate along axis 1. You can find documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html).

More generally, you can also use

```
stacked = np.concatenate(Z, axis=1)
```

which works for higher-dimensional arrays, too. The corresponding documentation is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by the numpy stuff, but now I see what you were asking. You just have your list comprehension inside out.

Rather than

```
z1 = [ np.concatenate( z[ii], 1 ) for ii in range(0,len(z)) ]
```

You want

```
z1 = np.concatenate((z[ii] for ii in range(0, len(z)), 1)
```

Note that I changed it to a generator expresssion, as you don't really care about the intermediate list.

Comment: You can also just pass `z` rather than wrapping it in an iterator.

Comment: @TillHoffmann Nice - I am terribly unfamiliar with Numpy, only used it a couple of times in college.