# how to merge several arrays stored in list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to concatenate several arrays store in list. Length of the arrays are different. I already read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798629/python-concatenate-arrays-in-a-list), but unfortunately I could not solve my problem. This is is simplified input data:

```
arr_all= [array([[1 ,2 , 10],
                 [5, 8, 3]]),
          array([[1, 0, 5]]),
          array([[0, 1, 8]]),
          array([[9, 13, 0]]),
          array([[2, 10, 2],
                 [1.1, 3, 3]]),
          array([[25, 0, 0]])]
n_data_sets=2
n_repetition=3
```

Now, I want to merge (concatenate) the first array of `arr_all` (`arr_all[0]`) with the fourth one (`arr_all[3]`), the second (`arr_all[1]`) with the fifth one (`arr_all[4]`) and the third one (`arr_all[2]`) with the last one (`arr_all[5]`). In fact here I have two data sets (`n_data_sets=2`) which are repeated three times (`n_repetition=3`). In reality I have several data sets that are repeated tens of times. I want to put each data set in a single array of my list. I can say the input is sorted based on the repetition but I want make it based on the data sets of each repetition. My expected result is:

```
arr_all= [array([[1, 2 , 10],
                 [5, 8, 3],
                 [9, 13, 0]]),
          array([[1, 0, 5],
                 [2, 10, 2],
                 [1.1, 3, 3]]),
          array([[0, 1, 8],
                 [25, 0, 0]])]
```

My input data was a list with six arrays (`n_repetition` times `n_data_sets`) but my result has `n_repetition` arrays.
In advance I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: use a double for loop and `range(i,len(arr_all),n_repetition)` in the inner loop, or `range(i+n_repetition,len(arr_all),n_repetition)` if you take element `[i]` to start the concatenation with

Comment: Dear @rioV8. Thanks for the feed back. Can you please explain it a little bit more? How can I use a double for loop? I do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further Alexander's response, this is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

arr_all = [np.array([[1, 2, 10], [5, 8, 3]]),
           np.array([[1, 0, 5]]),
           np.array([[0, 1, 8]]),
           np.array([[9, 13, 0]]),
           np.array([[2, 10, 2], [1.1, 3, 3]]),
           np.array([[25, 0, 0]])]
n_data_sets = 2
n_repetition = 3

new_array = []
for i in range(n_repetition):
    dataset = arr_all[i]
    for j in range(n_data_sets-1):
        dataset = np.concatenate([dataset, arr_all[i+(n_repetition*(j+1))]])
    new_array.append(dataset)

print(new_array)
```

I also found a cleaner method, but which is possibly worse in terms of time:

```
import numpy as np

arr_all = [np.array([[1, 2, 10], [5, 8, 3]]),
           np.array([[1, 0, 5]]),
           np.array([[0, 1, 8]]),
           np.array([[9, 13, 0]]),
           np.array([[2, 10, 2], [1.1, 3, 3]]),
           np.array([[25, 0, 0]])]
n_data_sets = 2
n_repetition = 3

reshaped = np.reshape(arr_all, (n_repetition, n_data_sets), order='F')

new = []

for arr in reshaped:
    new.append(np.concatenate(arr))

print(new)
```

Comment: Dear @Jonathan, this is exactly what I needed. I appreciate it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Two merge always the first half with the seconds half (if this was your intention), you can do something like this (which will work if you have an even amount of arrays.

```
import numpy as np

arr_all= [np.array([[1 ,2 , 10],
                 [5, 8, 3]]),
          np.array([[1, 0, 5]]),
          np.array([[0, 1, 8]]),
          np.array([[9, 13, 0]]),
          np.array([[2, 10, 2],
                 [1.1, 3, 3]]),
          np.array([[25, 0, 0]])]
          
half = int(len(arr_all)/2)

new = []
for i in range(half):
    new.append(np.concatenate((arr_all[i],arr_all[i+half]), axis=0))

print(new)
```

Comment: Dear @Alexander Riedel. Thanks for your solution. The point is that lots of the times it cannot be a half. In my simplified it is a half but if I have three repetitions for three data sets, then my input will have 9 arrays but i want to have three ones.